# Using a external variable in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a script which generates a numbered file..

like this:

`set no 0`

`file fn [open log_file_$no w]`

I want to remember this `no` every time I run the script, i.e when running for the first time, the file name should be `log_file_0` , 2nd time it should be `log_file_1` etc.

Is there a way to "remember" the value of the variable so that it can be used later?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking exactly. Could you perhaps give some more context?

Comment: I will be, more than once, running the script, thus generating the log_file everytime. I don't want to loose the previously generated files thus creating files with numbered names like shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a variable, you have the number you need in the file list:

```
set no [scan [lindex [lsort -dictionary [glob log_file_*]] end] log_file_%2d]

incr no

set fn [open log_file_$no w]
```

Let's break that up a bit. Create a list of log files:

```
set filelist [glob log_file_*]
```

Sort the list in dictionary order (where 10 comes after 2) and pick the last element:

```
set highest_numbered [lindex [lsort -dictionary $filelist] end]]
```

Extract the number from the file name:

```
set no [scan $highest_numbered log_file_%2d]
```

Increase the number and open a new log file:

```
incr no
set fn [open log_file_$no w]
```

If there is a possibility that no log files exist, the `glob` command will fail. To take care of this case, either do this:

```
set filelist [glob -nocomplain log_file_*]
if {[llength $filelist]} {
    set highest_numbered [lindex [lsort -dictionary $filelist] end]]
    set no [scan $highest_numbered log_file_%2d]
} else {
    set no 0
}
incr no
set fn [open log_file_$no w]
```

or this slightly safer version (if you have Tcl 8.6):

```
try {
    glob log_file_*
} on ok filelist {
    set highest_numbered [lindex [lsort -dictionary $filelist] end]
    set no [scan $highest_numbered log_file_%2d]
} trap {TCL OPERATION GLOB NOMATCH} {} {
    set no 0
} on error message {
    puts stderr "error when listing log files: $message"
    set no -1
}
if {$no > -1} {
    incr no
    set fn [open log_file_$no w]
    # ...
    chan close $fn
}
```

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [glob](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [try](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm)

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned elsewhere is me, I used that nick earlier.)

Comment: This is not working. It shows the error:%Error opening flash:log_file_0 (File in use in an incompatible mode)can't read "log_file_": no such variable
    while executing
"close $log_file_$no
"

Comment: @aro Hmm, well, for the last one, you shouldn't have a `$` before 'log'. For the first one, is another program/script/something else using the log file?

Comment: last error gone, i used `close $fn` but it now shows:
`no files matched glob pattern "log_file_*"
    while executing
"glob log_file_*"
    invoked from within
"set filelist [glob log_file_*]"`

Comment: use `glob -nocomplain ...` to shush that error, then check the `llength` of the returned list. If it is empty, then `set no 0`

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the value to disk somehow. Hoodiecrow gives you one sensible way to do it: in the actual filename. Other options:

1. in a config file somewhere
2. in a database (sqlite is good for this)

---

Demo for (1)

```
    # read the value
    if {[file exists num.dat]} {
        set fh [open num.dat r]
        set no [read -nonewline $fh]
        close $fh
    } else {
        set no 0
    }

    set logfile log_file_${no}

    # ...

    # write the value
    set fh [open num.dat w]
    puts $fh [incr no]
    close $fh
```

---

Demo for (2)

```
    package require Tcl 8.6
    package require tdbc::sqlite3

    set config_file config.db
    tdbc::sqlite3::connection create db $config_file

    # read the value
    if {[file exists $config_file]} {
        set stmt [$db prepare "create table config (number integer)"]
        $stmt execute
        $stmt close
        set no 0
    } else {
        set stmt [$db prepare "select number from config limit 1"]
        $stmt foreach row {
            set no [dict get $row number]
        }
        $stmt close
    }

    # ...

    # write the value
    set stmt [$db prepare "update config set number=:new limit 1"]
    $stmt execute [dict create new [incr no]]
    $stmt close

    $db close
```